# Create multi-command pipeline producer command

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

Kind of blanking on how to do this right:

```
{
    echo Hello1;
    usleep 500000 ;# sleep 500,000 microseconds
    echo Hello2;

} | node break-out-of-loop.js
```

I just want to issue some stdin and delay some of the commands. Is the above any different from:

```
(
    echo Hello1;
    usleep 500000 ;# sleep 500,000 microseconds
    echo Hello2;

) | node break-out-of-loop.js
```

or is there something better than those? I guess of course you could put the 3 commands in a bash function, but looking for something inline in this case.

Comment: "is there something better than those?" – Define "better". In what way those are not good for you?

Comment: they seem to work, just seems a little awkward, I don't remember the difference between {} amd ()

Comment: @AlexanderMills ah, that would be a separate question! So, the difference is that `{}` does *not* create a subshell (i.e. the things inside are run in the same shell, with the same visible variables modifying the same shell state etc), while `()` does create a subshell, i.e. what you do inside is separate from what the rest of the shell is doing. In your example, it makes no difference. But your reality is more complex, likely. Try running `a=foo; ( a=bar; echo inside $a; ) ; echo outside $a` vs `a=foo; { a=bar; echo inside $a; } ; echo outside $a` to see the difference.

Comment: ok cool, so only real difference is subshell vs not, I guess?

Comment: not the only "real" difference, the only difference. That's the point of these different parentheses.

Comment: PS: the domain in your profile has been grabbed by a domain reseller. You might want to remove that link ;)